# The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(System.Uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

How to overcome:

> The best overloaded method match for
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetAsync(System.Uri,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken)' has some invalid arguments?

```cs
string responseData = Convert.ToString(dr["jsonSample"]);
var data = Json.Decode(responseData);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56486/api/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
        .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client
        .GetAsync("SiteMaster/RFAISubmissionTest",data);
}
```

I am new to api, don't know how to solve it.
Please help...

Comment: Unrelated: [You are using HttpClient wrong](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: You cannot send JSON via HTTP GET; GET requests do not have a body. You either need to switch to POST, or use a query string instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are the overloads for the GetAsync method:** 
*The problem is your data attribute...*

For more information look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netcore-3.1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the HTTP specification is not entirely clear, many libraries do not permit you to use a GET query with a body, as the comment says, GET should use querystring and if you want a body, you need to use POST or PUT.

If you instead call `PostAsync()`, you can pass HttpContent which is built using various `HttpContent` subclasses, in your case, probably `System.Net.Http.Json.JsonContent` would be best.